# Bios password remove/reset

Tags: bios, passwords

How I Edit platform.ini file insyde bios to remove/reset my forgotten supervisor password bios? also check this

```
“TECH NOTE: How To Remove A Bios Password From an Insyde H2O EFI BIOS [UPDATED]”
```

but that method to edit platform.ini dose not work for me. Regards

my note book is acer aspire a715 71g

bios version is insyde h20

link to platform.ini : https://ufile.io/vh285

Comment: Try this [website](https://bios-pw.org/).

Comment: thanks man but that works for  8 digit password recovery key . my password rec. key is 10 digit... any body have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the website [bios-pw.org](https://bios-pw.org/) for unlocking
the BIOS, with the following procedure:

1. Enter 3 times the wrong code in answer to the prompt
2. The prompt will change, asking for a password
3. Press <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and a reset key will be displayed
4. Enter that key in [bios-pw.org](https://bios-pw.org/) and receive a code
5. Enter that code in the BIOS and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get into the BIOS
6. In the BIOS go into the tab that might be named "Security", and click an entry
   which might be named "Set Supervisor Password".
7. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
8. It may ask for the old password, so enter the code from step 4
9. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> for all prompts for a new password (or enter a password)
10. Exit the BIOS with saving the changes
11. Done. At your discretion you may donate to that website.

This should work, but if it doesn't, see the article
[How To Remove, Clear, Reveal, Unlock or Reset BIOS Security Password](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-reset-remove-clear-or-reveal-cmos-bios-security-password/2/)
for useful utilities: PC CMOS Cleaner, CmosPwd by CGSecurity,
!Bios by eleventh alliance and invalidating the CMOS checksum manually
while booting from FreeDOS.

Other useful articles are:

- [6 Ways To Reset or Remove BIOS Password For Acer, Dell, HP, Toshiba, Asus and Apple Laptop](https://www.geckoandfly.com/6940/reset-or-remove-bios-password-for-acer-dell-hp-toshiba-asus-and-apple-laptop/)
  which is more hardware-oriented.
- [Reset BIOS Password](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/550512/reset-bios-password)

Comment: THANKS bro but my recovry key has 10 digits and my bios is insyde h20 v1.2 thats not rest passwords by these ways... any idea?

Comment: i try to change it and it works... but i dont know witch parts need to changed... any idea? please look that ini file i attached

Comment: I don't know that utility. Watch the video at the end of [my link](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/550512/reset-bios-password) for an example of the BIOS settings to modify.

Comment: THANKS but i test that ways and no one works for my system.. my insyde bios in not listed for master passwords... how ever please check this article too and help me : https://713itsupport.com/blog/2011/06/how-to-remove-a-bios-password-from-an-insyde-h2o-efi-bios/            the way you test in that video works for 8 digit bios password recovery key but my recovery key is 10 digits any way. Regars

Answer (score 0):

Quite often, the password will be set (either in plaintext or hashed) in a separate EEPROM in the computer, so that the ROM for the BIOS has no effect on it. This also means that you can upgrade  or reinstall the BIOS and keep your password and settings on there. This is a huge convenience for businesses, who do not disclose BIOS passwords to employees, yet can still remotely upgrade them. You may have to decrypt or re-flash the security EEPROM or another chip to reset the password, as you might have seen in older style Thinkpads for example.

To answer your question, you should research how to clear the password on the specific model you have - that is, of course, provided you own the machine or have full permission to do so by the owner. It may not (and frankly, shouldn't) be possible any more to do so by simply removing the CMOS battery, but neverless its something to try anyhow. In the worst case scenario, you could learn how to reverse engineer the BIOS chip and inject code to reset it for you, if you are not able to do so manually. This is overkill and it much easier said than done, but then again, if you are willing to decompile the binary from the BIOS you might as well get it commercially done for you or just get another board. All the personal examples I've seen of BIOS disassembly have been done for one's own interest, and simply isn't worth the time to learn (especially since, from your question, it appears you want a quick and easy way of wiping the password).

Comment: thanks for answer my Q but still i think its possible to remove or reset password from this file cause many old models of this bramd(Acer) passwords removed by this method...thats why i still persis this may happen for my motebook too and i want you to read that ini file and check what parts i need to change to remove that! regards

Comment: The platform.ini contains a few lines to do with password checking - perhaps tinker with these and flash the BIOS to see if it will work. However, I highly doubt that a single text file can affect the password capabilities of a BIOS - this seems too easy an attack on a system that is so low level. Perhaps you can use the text inside to your advantage, should you decide to modify the BIOS - for e.g, "0 is returned when the correct password is entered". In any case, we cannot tell you what is definitively correct since I do not have the machine to hand to test.

Comment: i try to change it and it works... but i dont know witch parts need to changed... any idea? please look that ini file i attached

Answer (score 0):

Your computer uses a newer version of Insyde H20 BIOS with a 10 digit lock seed. This lock can be circumvented. Go to this [website](https://let-def.github.io/insydious/) and enter your 10 digit key to get your unlock password.