# Remove/reset EFI/BIOS/firmware password

Tags: boot, uefi, password-recovery

I set up a UEFI password on my new PC. I decided to remove it and in order to do that I booted in UEFI settings. Clicked on reset administrator password. I've put the old password and nothing on the new password and confirmation. Save.

Expected behaviour: At startup the system no longer prompts for password

Actual behaviour: I'm still prompted for a password before windows boot, I tried the old password and pressing enter with no password at all. I can't boot and I can't access UEFI settings anymore. I tried booting from a Debian liveUSB and also a Windows 10 Recovery USB but that's not working

Comment: What is the make/model of your computer?

Comment: Please click [edit] and add the PC's make and model (or if a whitebox, the make and model of the motherboard). Please do not click Add Comments as new comments squeeze old comments offscreen; your facts about the situation should go in the Question. Adding links to photos of the UEFI/BIOS/Firmware settings screens taken with a cellphone camera and posted to http://imgur.com could also be very helpful

Comment: I managed to log back in. In case someone came here for reference I'm not sure what happened, it might be I actually successfully reset administrator password but there was also a UEFI user password

Comment: @K7AAY I think your title edit is incorrect, I have no BIOS installed as far as I understand. UEFI replaced it as for most of the new PCs

Comment: Does [this method](https://superuser.com/a/1414986/8672) work for UEFI?

Comment: @Riccardo - BIOS and UEFI are both firmware.  While I believe you should make improvements per the previous comments, if you disagree with the title change, you can change it to something else.  You don't need to specify what OS you are running in the title though.

Answer (score -1):

The solution I know is: unplug your computer from power (if you don't unplug, removing battery is pointless), open it up and remove the button cell/disk battery from the motherboard (commonly a CR2032). Sometimes there is a jumper to bleed the CMOS/BIOS but pulling the battery does the same thing. Wait a couple of minutes then put the battery back in and plug your PC back in and power it on - all CMOS/BIOS settings will have been set to factory default and no more password.

Comment: I read many posts suggesting something like this but noone was 100% sure it would work and my PC is new so I don't want to loose warranty if it's not necessary

Comment: @Riccardo I am 100% sure it will work. You won't loose your warranty by doing something anyone can do with their system: reset the CMOS/BIOS.

Comment: Your certainty is about to be shattered. No, it won't work because the passwords are saved by UEFI, reset won't remove it.

Comment: GabrielaGarcia is right; settings of firmware will be retained for years without a battery and power. That's why I suggested you tell us the make and model of your PC or motherboard. However, if you ever have to do something similar, actions like this will not void your warranty.